# Issue with jQuery when fetching data using .load()

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

I have a table that when a row is clicked it sends the first 6 characters of that row (an ID) to a PHP page and loads the subsequent data into a div further down the page. The issue it seems is that once I click a row to load the div, The majority of the jQuery events stop working (.hover, .sortElements) these are attached to the original table. Is there anyone that would know a 'fix' or work around for this issue or is there something I am just missing.

```
<SCRIPT type='text/javascript'>
$(document).ready(function(){

$(".panel").hide();
$(".itemjobbutton").click(function(){
    $(".panel").slideToggle("200");
    return false;
});
var inverse = false;
$("#jobTable th").click(function(){
            var header = $(this),
                index = header.index();

            header
                .closest('table')
                .find('td')
                .filter(function(){
                    return $(this).index() === index;
                })
                .sortElements(function(a, b){

                    a = $(a).text();
                    b = $(b).text();

                    return (
                        isNaN(a) || isNaN(b) ?
                            a > b : +a > +b
                        ) ?
                            inverse ? -1 : 1 :
                            inverse ? 1 : -1;

                }, function(){
                    return this.parentNode;
                });

            inverse = !inverse;

        });

$('#jobTable tr').click(function(){
if($(this).index() != 0) {
    var thistext = $(this).text().substring(0,6);
    $("#joblistingDetail").load('jobview.php' , {jobID: thistext}).hide().slideDown('100');
    $("#jobTable tr").css("background", "#fff");
    $(this).closest('tr').css('background-color', '#C3D9FF');
}
});


});

$('#jobTable tr').hover(

function() {
    $(this).addClass('hover');
},
function() {
    $(this).removeClass('hover')
}
);
```

Comment: JobView has #jobTable bringing in to the main page?

Comment: Is `#joblistingDetail` an ancestor of `#jobTable`? If so, you need to do event delegation originating from the `#joblistingDetail` element.

Comment: @Panagiotis yes that is correct.

Comment: @KevinB '#jobListingDetail' only contains the information that is supplied by the jobview page

Comment: @sinopia If the table isn't being replaced/regenerated, the events should still be bound. Are any errors being thrown?

Comment: @KevinB `Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'sortElements'
(anonymous function)
jQuery.event.dispatchjquery-latest.js
jQuery.event.add.elemData.handle.eventHandle` is thrown back after jobview is loaded, but not before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `jobview.php` is more than likely including it's own version of `jquery.js` that is overriding the one on the parent page. Either remove it from `jobview.php`, or modify your `.load` to only pull in html from within a given selector such as

```
$("#joblistingDetail").load('jobview.php #target')
```

where `#target` is a selector selecting a specific container to pull in.